# how to access SVN using VBScript

Tags: svn, api, vbscript

We'r maintaing some test scripts written in VBScript in SVN and everyday morning we get the latest copy of these files and run the tests. We are doing this manually at the moment. However we want to automated this whole operation.

How do we access SVN using VBScript to copy the latest code back to the test machine? Is there any API  that we can use to access SVN and get the latest files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So long as svn is in your path...

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.shell")
objShell.exec ("cmd svn update C:\Projects\Project1 --username buildrobot --password IAmARobot1")
```

Answer (score 0):

You *could* just call out to the system, and run the svn commandline client from the VBScript. This seems to be the easiest solution unless you have some extra demands on what needs to be done.